# A priori error estimates - finite element method - mixed boundary conditions

Tags: finite-element, reference-request

Consider the problem
$$  \left\{\begin{array} {rcl}
-\Delta u & =  0 & \text{ in } \Omega \\
u & =  0 & \text{ on } \Gamma_D \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} &= g &\text{ on } \Gamma_R \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} &= 0 &\text{ on } \Gamma_N
\end{array}\right.  $$
Where $g$ is a trace of a $H^{1+\varepsilon}(\Omega)$ function. An example of such a configuration in is shown in the Figure below.
[image]

I am aware that depending on the function $g$ the solution to this problem might be less regular than $H^2(\Omega)$. I am interested in reading about the a priori error estimates that can be obtained when solving this problem with triangular piecewise linear finite elements (P1, Lagrange).

My questions are:

- Is it possible to indicate a reference which treats in detail this classical case?
- What is the best convergence result that can be expected in this case in terms of the regularity properties of $u$? (i.e. what is the best exponent one can get in the estimate $\|u-u_h\|_{H^1(\Omega)}\leq Ch^\gamma$ when $u$ is not necessarily in $H^2$)